# javascript regexp match tag names

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't remember the name of it, but I believe you can reference already matched strings within a RegExp object. What I want to do is match all tags within a given string eg

```
<ul><li>something in the list</li></ul>
```

the RegExp should be able to match only the same tags, then I will use a recursive function to put all the individual matches in an array. The regex that should work if I can reference the first match would be.

```
var reg = /(?:<(.*)>(.*)<(?:FIRST_MATCH)\/>)/g;
```

The matched array should then contain

```
match[0] = "<ul><li>something in the list</li></ul>";
match[1] = "ul";
match[2] = ""; // no text to match
match[3] = "li";
match[4] = "something in the list";
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you mean backreference (`\1`, `\2`):

```
var s = '<ul><li>something in the list</li></ul>';
s.match(/<([^>]+)><([^>]+)>(.*?)<\/\2><\/\1>/)
// => ["<ul><li>something in the list</li></ul>",
//     "ul",
//     "li",
//     "something in the list"]
```

The result is not exactly same with what you want. But point is that the backreference `\1`, `\2` match the string that was matched by earlier group.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but that's not working. I have been reading since you posted and keep finding that backreferencing is not possible in Javascript. Maybe I could pass a function in a `String.replace()` and run another replace with the first tag name it see's then push that in an array.. I'll see if I can make it work.

Comment: @synthet1c, not working?   backreference is possible in Javascript. See http://ideone.com/sdmFmq (example run).  Also see [Regular expression guide in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (Find `back reference` in the page)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to parse HTML using regular expressions (if you're interested in the specifics, it is because HTML parsing requires a stronger type of automaton than a finite state automaton which is what a regular expression can express - look up FSA vs FST for more info).

You might be able to get away with some hack for a specific problem, but if you want to reliably parse HTML using Javascript then there are other ways to do this. Search the web for: parse html javascript and you'll get plenty of pointers on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I made a dirty workaround. Still needs work thought.

```
var str = '<div><ul id="list"><li class="something">this is the text</li></ul></div>';

function parseHTMLFromString(str){
    var structure = [];
    var matches = [];
    var reg = /(<(.+)(?:\s([^>]+))*>)(.*)<\/\2>/;
    str.replace(reg, function(){
        //console.log(arguments);
        matches.push(arguments[4]);
        structure.push(arguments[1], arguments[4]);
    });
    while(matches.length){
        matches.shift().replace(reg, function(){
            console.log(arguments);
            structure.pop();
            structure.push(arguments[1], arguments[4]);
            matches.push(arguments[4]);
        });
    }
    return structure;
}

// parseHTMLFromString(str); // ["<div>", "<ul id="list">", "<li class="something">", "this is the text"]
```